# how to identify process and not run rest of batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, ant, process

I'm using the following code to check whether there is a java process with the specific name.

```
for /f "tokens=1" %i in ('jps -m ^| find "TouchPosApplication"') do ( EXIT /B )
```

how can I use this as an if condition rather than iterating. and this command exits the batch code even if there is no process named such. is there any thing wrong with this code.

This is my entire batch script

```
start start-chrome.bat
for /f "tokens=1" %i in ('jps -m ^| find "TouchPosApplication"') do ( EXIT /B )
ant main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set var=False
start start-chrome.bat
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('jps -m ^| find "TouchPosApplication"') do set var=True

if "%var%"=="True" (
Echo Found
) else (
ant main
)
```

Comment: unfortunately the script exits with nothing happening. even there is no process name as such, the batch exists. it prints in the console that "i was unexpected at this time"

Comment: write `%%i` instead of `%i`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on phone so can't test it but

```
goto label
```

will jump to and execute `ant main` whereas `goto finish` would end program.

```
label:
ant main
finish:
```

PS. I don't recall batch accepting single quotes, which are apostrophes really.

Comment: ... and the apostrophes are part of the `for`-syntax.